# JavaScript file not loaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a file called `LocaleConverter`:

```
var LocaleConverter = (function() {

    return {
        convertLocale: function(localeToConvert) {
            switch (localeToConvert) {
                case 'en-US':
                    return 'en-US';
                case 'en-GB':
                    return 'en-GB';
                case 'es':
                case 'es-MX':
                    return 'es';
                case 'fr-FR':
                    return 'fr';
                case 'fr-CH':
                    return 'fr-CH';
                default:
                    return 'en-US';
            }
        }
    }

} ());
```

I am bringing in the script into my master page like:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/LocaleConverter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I try something like:

```
var convertedLocale = LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR");
```

It gives me an error telling me that convertedLocale does not exist when I try to use it elsewhere?

Comment: Have you verified using the Developer Tools of the browser that the js file is being loaded? If not, make sure your source location is correct. You can test this by just putting the address in the browser to download the file directly.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann - Yes, I checked with firebug, IE Developer tools.  I cleared the browser cache and restarted the web server, but no luck.

Comment: No luck, what? File not loading?

Comment: If the file is loading, then make sure your code using "LocalConverter" isn't getting run until after the js file is loaded.

Comment: What is your file structure? And when you open up the console do you have any red errors?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann - The file does not load.  The file is not included when I inspect the HTML.  I have checked the spelling as well

Comment: @Donte'Trumble - The structure is Root/Scripts/LocaleConverter.js

Comment: Can you download the file directly, aka is it at the location specified? Is the script tag in the rendered HTML sent to the browser?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann - The script tag is not rendered in the HTML, but I can download the file.

Comment: There's an issue with your master page then. What is the code in your master page?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann - Wow, it is like one big pile of spaghetti.  Is there any possible places I can look that might cause the issue.  Is is something that gets loaded before?

Comment: If the script tag is in the master page, then make sure there isn't an if/them causing it to not show. You'll have to trace through the code. I do suggest you do more troubleshooting first before just posting to StackOverlow for help next time.

Comment: So in your index.html page you are ../ twice to get to the js file? In your folder structure the js file lives inside Root/Scripts/. So you would need to go like this  Root/Scripts/LocaleConverter.js. If I am understanding this right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following statement and see if that works

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/LocaleConverter.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If that does do a trick, try to clean out the cache of your IIS pool or web browser cache. Or try clicking "Cntl + F5" to refresh.

Let me know if that works

Comment: You may have missed the statement for the OP to try.